# How to get custom shape using UIBezierPath and make it as subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, touch, uibezierpath

I am drawing a rect using `UIBezierPath`. The following code creates the rect in my view controller:

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    TargetAreaView *targetView;  //TargetAreaView is a subclass of UIView
    UIView *detectionView;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.size.height = frame.size.height - 200;
    detectionView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
    targetView = [[TargetAreaView alloc]initWithFrame:detectionView.frame];
    targetView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.view addSubview:targetView];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

I am using the bezier path to draw the rect in `TargetAreaView` class. 
I have used the following code in the `UIView` subclass:(TargetAreaView)

```
@interface TargetAreaView : UIView
{
    NSMutableArray *points;
    CGRect superViewFrame;
    CGPoint selectedPoint;
}

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self)
    {
        superViewFrame = frame;
        points = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(superViewFrame.size.width / 2 - 200/2, superViewFrame.size.height / 2 - 200/2);
        CGPoint heightPoint1 = CGPointMake(startPoint.x, startPoint.y + 200);
        CGPoint widthPoint1 = CGPointMake(startPoint.x + 200, startPoint.y + 200);
        CGPoint heightPoint2 = CGPointMake(startPoint.x + 200, startPoint.y);
        CGPoint widthPoint2 = CGPointMake(startPoint.x, startPoint.y);

        [points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:startPoint]];
        [points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:heightPoint1]];
        [points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:widthPoint1]];
        [points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:heightPoint2]];
        [points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:widthPoint2]];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if (points && points.count > 0)
    {
        [self drawTargetArea:points];
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}

-(void)drawTargetArea:(NSMutableArray *)savedPoints
{

    UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    // Set the starting point of the shape.
    for (int idx = 0; idx < savedPoints.count; idx++)
    {
        if (idx == 0)
        {
            NSValue *startPoint = [savedPoints objectAtIndex:idx];
            [aPath moveToPoint:startPoint.CGPointValue]; // Starting Point
        }
        else
        {
            NSValue *drawPoints = [savedPoints objectAtIndex:idx];
            [aPath addLineToPoint:drawPoints.CGPointValue]; // Add lines from previous to current point
        }
    }
    [aPath closePath]; // close the final path

    aPath.lineWidth = 10.0f;
    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
    [aPath stroke];
}
```

The above `UIView` subclass code generates the rect as shown below:

[image]

I have written the logic to move the corners of rect to change its shape as shown below:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint startTouchPoint  = [touch locationInView:self]; //get the user touch position and check it is nearer in 10px range to any of the position in rect
    for (NSValue *aPoint in points)
    {
        CGPoint currentPoint = aPoint.CGPointValue;
        CGFloat distance = [self touchPositionDifference:startTouchPoint WithCornerPosition:currentPoint]; // Calculate the distance between user touch position and rect points
        if (distance < 10)
        {
            selectedPoint = currentPoint; // get the nearest point in a global variable
            break;
        }
    }
}

-(CGFloat)touchPositionDifference:(CGPoint)touchPosition WithCornerPosition:(CGPoint)cornnerPosition
{
    CGFloat dx= touchPosition.x - cornnerPosition.x;
    CGFloat dy= touchPosition.y - cornnerPosition.y;
    CGFloat distance= sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);

    return distance; // calculate and return distance between two points
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchEndPoint  = [touch locationInView:self];
     for (int idx = 0; idx < points.count; idx++)
    {
        NSValue *aPoint = [points objectAtIndex:idx];
        CGPoint currentPoint = aPoint.CGPointValue;
        if (CGPointEqualToPoint(currentPoint, selectedPoint)) 
        {
            [points replaceObjectAtIndex:idx withObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:touchEndPoint]]; // get the global point value and touch ended value and replace the new value with old value
        }
    }
    [self setNeedsDisplay];// and draw the shape with new points
}
```

I can able to get the output like following

[image]

I have return code to get the bezier path as follows:

```
-(UIBezierPath *)getPath
{
    if (points.count <= 0) return nil;
    NSArray *oldPoints = points;

    UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    // Set the starting point of the shape.
    CGPoint p1 = [[oldPoints objectAtIndex:0] CGPointValue];
    [aPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(p1.x, p1.y)];

    for (uint i=1; i<oldPoints.count; i++)
    {
        CGPoint p = [[oldPoints objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue];
        [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(p.x, p.y)];
    }
    [aPath closePath];
    return aPath; //This returns me a bezier path of the already drawn shape
}
```

I am getting the entire view(within that view i am having the irregular shape View is represented in green color and the shape is represented in red border color)  as shown below

[image]

I want to get that particular shape alone(the irregular shape) As shown below

How can I achieve this? Am I following the right path?

[image]

Comment: @Rob I need to get the shape alone as a view I have added the image Please refer it

Comment: @Rob Previously I had created view in  a position X = 200, y = 200,Width  = 200, Height = 200 (let name it as "A" view). If user touches anywhere on the screen i will get the user touch position and if that position lies inside the "A" view I have handled  it as follows BOOL status= CGRectContainsPoint("A"View, "User Touch Position"); but now I am trying to make the "A" View Dynamic Thats why I have used the bezier path. Now I am able to draw the shape dynamically how can i check the above condition. Now are you able to understand my question?

Comment: @Rob If I mask it, it showing the rect alone but when i try to detect it with the User touch position with the CGRectContainsPoint condition it fails because it has the entire View. I dont want it as image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78414/discussion-between-rob-and-peer-mohamed-thabib).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to draw the above mentioned shape.

```
- (void)drawCanvas1WithFrame: (CGRect)frame
 {
//// Color Declarations
UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithRed: 1 green: 0 blue: 0 alpha: 1];

//// Bezier Drawing
UIBezierPath* bezierPath = UIBezierPath.bezierPath;
[bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 77.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 39.5)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 130.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 14.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 130.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 14.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 130.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 14.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 122.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 75.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 61.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 110.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 77.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 39.5)];
[UIColor.greenColor setFill];
[bezierPath fill];
[color setStroke];
bezierPath.lineWidth = 1;
[bezierPath stroke];
}
```

Comment: I think you miss understood my question I am able to draw the shape using Bezire Path but I am unable to get the shape alone as UIView

Comment: so you want to crop particular path and instantiate it as another uiview?

Comment: Exactly, I need to instantiate the shape as a separate view